# Trying to hide/reveal a DIV based on a PHP loop

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP loop that returns a series of "talks" in a conference agenda. There is a description associated with each talk.

I have pasted the code here: https://pastebin.com/ckD380iN

```
<?php
                $args = array('pagename' => 'agenda');
                $agenda_page = new WP_Query($args);

                if($agenda_page->have_posts()) : while($agenda_page->have_posts()) : $agenda_page->the_post();
                    ?>

            <section class="content">


            <h3><?php the_field('agenda_list_title'); ?></h3>
            <?php the_field('agenda_list_intro_paragraph'); ?>

                        <?php the_content(); ?>

                        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>



                 <ul class="event-list">
                    <?php
                            $agenda_posts = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'agenda', 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'ASC'));
                            while ($agenda_posts->have_posts()) : $agenda_posts->the_post();

                                if( get_field('2021_agenda')) {
                        ?>

                            <li class="event" id="agendastart">
                                <div class="event-time">

                                    <?php
                                    if (have_rows('time_begin')):
                                    while (have_rows('time_begin')) : the_row();

                                    $time = get_sub_field('time');
                                    $time = ltrim($time, '0');
                                    echo $time;
                                    the_sub_field('am/pm');

                                    endwhile;
                                    endif;

                                    echo ' ' . __('&ndash;') . ' ';

                                    if (have_rows('time_end')):
                                    while (have_rows('time_end')) : the_row();

                                    $time = get_sub_field('time');
                                    $time = ltrim($time, '0');
                                    echo $time;
                                    the_sub_field('am/pm');

                                    endwhile;
                                    endif;
                                    ?>
                                </div>

                                <?php edit_post_link('[Edit Event]', '<div class="edit-link">', '</div>'); ?>
                                <div class="indent">

                                    <?php

                                    $c = 0;
                                    if (have_rows('talks')):
                                    while (have_rows('talks')) : the_row();

                                    $title = get_sub_field('title');
                                    $subtitle = get_sub_field('subtitle');
                                    $description = get_sub_field('description');
                                    $i = get_the_id();
                                    ?>

                                    <div class="pretitle"><?=$title;?></div>

                                    <?php if ($subtitle) : ?>

                                        <div class="event-title">
                                            <?php $content = get_sub_field('description'); if ($content) : ?>

                                                  <?php echo $subtitle; ?>
                                                  <br><button onclick="myFunction(myDiv<?php echo $x; ?>)">More Details</button>
                                        </div>

<div id="myDIV<?php echo $x; ?>"><?php $i++ ;?><?php echo $description; ?> <?php else: ?> <?php echo $subtitle; ?> <?php endif; ?> </div>

                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                    <ul class="speaker-list">


                                        <?php
                                        $speakers = get_sub_field('speakers');

                                        if ($speakers) :
                                            foreach ($speakers as $speaker) :

                                            $label = '';
                                            $mod = get_field('moderator', $speaker->ID);
                                            $intr = get_field('intro_speaker', $speaker->ID);

                                            if ($mod == true) :
                                                $label = ' <span style="color:' . get_field('primary_branding_color', 'options') . '">(moderator)</span>';
                                            endif;

                                            if ($intr == true) :
                                                $label = ' <span style="color: #35a6c4">(introduction)</span>';
                                            endif;

                                            ?>

<li>

<a class='iframe' href="<?php echo get_permalink($speaker->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($speaker->ID); ?></a><?php echo $label; ?>

    <?php the_field('job_title', $speaker->ID); ?>
</li>

                                            <?php
                                            endforeach;
                                        endif; ?>

                                    </ul>

                                    <?php
                                        $c++;
                                    endwhile;
                                    endif;
                                    ?>


                                </div>
                            </li>

                            <?php } endwhile; ?>

                        </ul>

            </section>
```

Lines 61-86 are the relevant parts, starting with $c = 0;

I have this script as well:

```
[script>]
function myFunction(index) { 
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV"+index);
    if (x.style.display === "block"){
        x.style.display = "none"; 
    } 
    else { 
        x.style.display = "block";
    }
}
[/script]
```

The page is rendered here: https://mitcfo.artisanovens.com/agendapage/

I am hoping to get the descriptions to appear when you click More Details, but the myDIV code is not differentiating between descriptions of each panel. (In source code they are all myDIV which is a problem.)

I've tried unsuccessfully to append a differentiating element to make each DIV unique.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if it's the problem, but at your onclick="myFunction(myDiv<?php echo $x; ?>)". See, you're sending the parameter "myDiv" without quotes. And your function receives just the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things to observe. First, with `myFunction(myDiv<?php echo $x; ?>)` (ex: myFunction(myDiv2336)) you pass the whole HTMLDivElement object to your function. Why not.

Then, in your function `myFunction`, at the level of `var x = document.getElementById("myDIV"+index);`, you seek to retrieve an element by its id, when you are already passing the entire object to it. (and then there is a typo error **myDiv** versus **myDIV**).

If you want to keep this strategy, you have to modify your function to:

```
function myFunction(index) {
  if (index.style.display == "block" || index.style.display == "") {
    index.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    index.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

You can find a working example here https://jsfiddle.net/j86a0g5z/

You can also pass only the id when calling your function `myFunction(<?php echo $x;?>) (ex: myFunction(2336))` and then retrieve the object with `var x = document.getElementById("myDiv"+index)`. Pay attention to the spelling of myDiv ;)

Comment: @Christopher Reichert, were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: I think I got what you are saying!  I now have it functioning on the site: https://mitcfo.artisanovens.com/agendapage/ so TY TY .

Comment: I think I got what you are saying!  I now have it functioning on the site: https://mitcfo.artisanovens.com/agendapage/ so TY TY.

One last thing: How do I get the display to be set to none on initial page load? I've tried swapping the block and none, but not getting any success.

https://jsfiddle.net/creichert/my3tf4uw/1/

Comment: @ChristopherReichert, Glad your issue is resolved. To hide by default the content more details you can simply add <div id="myDiv2336" style="display: none">

Comment: And if my answer answers your question please don't forget to mark it on the site as accepted, as well as useful (also click on the up arrow). Thanks.

Comment: @ChristopherReichert, does it answer your question?

Comment: Hi,  Thanks...adding the style="display: none" did the trick.  My last challenge is one that I suspect is beyond this thread, but I'll throw it out there, just in case.  It turns out that because the agenda items that are repeater Advanced Custom Fields, share the same post ID, so for ex on the 130pm Track 2 descrip. it opens only the Track 1 desc from that same time frame.  I need to figure out a unique $i = get_the_id(); that I guess doesn't use the ID.  I'm hoping that there is a way to find that in the SQL DB in WP. sigh.

Comment: Hope so too. Good luck. And thank you.